# Why does my bread still smell like yeast?

Tags: baking, bread, yeast

I wonder why my bread still have a yeasty smell? Did I put too much yeast? I use instant yeast, 11g for 500g wheat flour. Is that too much yeast for that amount of flour?

Comment: I only use about 7-8g of yeast for that amount of flour. Is the crumb (inside) still too moist?

Answer (score 5):

You are using to much dried yeast.
11 gr should be used with fresh yeast.

To get an idea, divide the amount of fresh yeast with 2,5, so you should only use 5 gr (11:2.5) of dried yeast.

Answer (score 3):

Active dry yeast would (depending on amount of salt, water, sugar, etc.) probably be around 0.5–1.5% of the flour weight; so that'd be 2.5–7.5g of yeast. Instant yeast is slightly less, maybe 0.4%–1.2%, or 4–6g.

Generally speaking, using less yeast results in longer rise times and better flavor. At some point, though, if you use little enough, you'll have very long rise time (over a day) and sourdough (as lactobacilli take up residence).

Also generally speaking, salt slows yeast growth (so, the more salt, the more yeast added) and water speeds yeast growth (so, higher hydration breads use less yeast).